# "No Extension exists for streamingml" error in WSO2 SP

Tags: wso2, event-stream-processing

When I try using `#streamingml` extension in WSO2 SP, I get the error that extension is not available.
However I have made sure that `siddhi-execution-streamingml-1.0.15` is downloaded and placed within the `/lib` directory.

I am running this on Ubuntu 16.04 as a docker service. I have downloaded the extension and have placed it under the /lib directory.

```
@info(name = 'training-query')
from ProductionTrainingStream**#streamingml:updateHoeffdingTree**('SweetTypeModel', 5, density, volume, sweetType)
select *
insert into TemporaryStream;
```

Comment: Which version of SP are you using? Can you try using the latest version of that jar if you are using the latest version of SP? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wso2.extension.siddhi.execution.streamingml/siddhi-execution-streamingml/1.1.1

Comment: Thanks Lakshan. Version I am using is SP430. I will try this extension and see if this helps me solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Lakshan, I tried it with the latest version siddhi-execution-streamingml-1.1.1.jar. Still no luck. I continue to get the same error. Do I have to perform some action after saving the extension file under $SP_HOME/lib folder? Like import the extension in editor or add it to some config file or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HoeffdingTree classification is supported by the [siddhi-gpl-execution-streamingml](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-gpl-execution-streamingml/api/1.0.20/#hoeffdingtreeclassifier-stream-processor).
Download its latest version from [maven](https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/wso2gpl/content/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/gpl/execution/streamingml/siddhi-gpl-execution-streamingml/1.0.20/siddhi-gpl-execution-streamingml-1.0.20.jar) and copy it to SP_HOME/lib directory.